# GLM and fisher.test give different conclusion regarding factor significance

Tags: generalized-linear-model, fishers-exact-test

I would like to test the significance of a binary factor `cropBin` on a binary variables `scaleBin`.

Here is the data :

```
dput(test) 
structure(list(cropBin = c(1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 
1, 0, 1, 1), scaleBin = c(1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -16L), class = "data.frame", .Names = c("cropBin", 
"scaleBin"))
```

When I run a `glm` (binomial) on the data :

```
summary(glm(data = test, cropBin ~ scaleBin, family = binomial))
```

The p-value of assocated with `scaleBin` is 0.996

When I run a `fisher.test` on the same data :

```
fisher.test(test$scaleBin, test$cropBin)
```

The pvalue is 0.006993.

I know this question may seem very broad but why am I getting such different outputs in terms of significance?

Comment: The large standard errors suggest complete or quasi-complete separation (which you can actually can see with `table(test)`) and there's perfect negative dependence between the intercept and the predictor (put your glm fit into `vcov`, though the opposite sign and near equality of magnitude of the intercept and coefficient is a bit of a giveaway). Try some searches on complete separation and quasi-complete separation. Note that the 2x2 chi-square statistic has a p-value not so very far from the Fisher test.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that in your dataset `scaleBin=0` necesairly gives `cropBin=1`. This results with large uncertainity of parameter estimation in GLM. See how large standard error is there.

To play with those data, change one last `cropBin` from 1 to 0 and see what happens.